# How to simplify an expression that does not have a common factor

Tags: calculus

I am trying to simplify this expression :

$$9a^4 + 12a^2b^2 + 4b^4$$

So I ended up having this :

$$(3a^2)^2 + 2(3a^2)(2b^2) + (2b^2)^2$$

However, after that I don't know how to keep on simplifying the equation, it is explained that the answer is $(3a^2 + 2b^2)^2$ because the expression is equivalent to $(x + y)^2$ but I don't understand how they get to that ?

Comment: If the answers below did not suffice, then I guess you're questioning the meaning of a simplification. That however, is unlikely to be answered on math SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following formula.

$x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = (x+y)^2$

Here $x = 3a^2$, $y = 2b^2$

On putting values in left hand side of above formula.

$(3a^2)^2+2(3a^2)(2b^2)+(2b^2)^2 = 9a^4+12a^2b^2+4b^4 = (3a^2+2b^2)^2$

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula

$$x^2+2xy+y^2=(x+y)^2$$

here, we let $x=3a^2$ and $y=2b^2$

Comment: What do you call that formula?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a special name to it. but it is a special case of binomial expansion. $(x+y)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n\begin{pmatrix} n \\ i \end{pmatrix}x^iy^{n-i}$

Answer (score 1):

Try expanding: $$(3a^2 +2b^2)^2=(3a^2+2b^2)(3a^2+2b^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

$$(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$$

If $x=3a^2$ and $y=2b^2$, we end up with

$$(3a^2+2b^2)^2=(3a^2)^2+2(3a^2)(2b^2)+(2b^2)^2\\=9a^4+12a^2b^2+4b^4$$

Answer (score 0):

after the binomial formula $$(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$$ we get: $$(3a^2+2b^2)^2=9a^4+12a^2b^2+4b^4$$